# What is the relationship between the set of all explicitly defined integer sequences, and implicitly defined integer sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations

An explicitly defined integer sequence is one in which the $n^{\text{th}}$ term can be calculated as a function of $n$.

An implicitly defined integer sequence is one in which the $n^{\text{th}}$ term can be calculated as a function of some previous terms of the series.

For instance, the Fibonacci sequence $(0,1,1,2,3,5,8,\dotsc)$ is defined implicitly as $F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)$. The Fibonacci sequence can also be defined explicitly, as $$F(n) = \frac{G^n - (1-G)^n}{\sqrt{5}}\quad \text{where}\ G = \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$$

My questions are:

1. Can all explicitly defined integer sequences be defined implicitly? If not, how can we tell which ones can?
2. Can all implicitly defined integer sequences be defined explicitly? If not, how can we tell which ones can?

For (1), my conjecture is that all explicitly defined integer sequences can be defined implicitly. For instance, the sequence $F(x) = x^2$ can be defined implicitly as $F(x) = 2F(x-1) - F(x-2) + 2$. Similar expressions can be found for any polynomial function. I presume that implicit definitions can also be found for exponential, periodic and other types of explicitly defined sequences.

For (2), I have not much idea here.

Comment: Well, what is explicitly expressed? Written in terms of polynomials, and exponentials? Or is it something more abstract involving deeper ideas of algebra? The sequence $F(n) = 2^{F(n-1)}$ $F(0)=1$ implicitly defines a recursive sequence, an explicit expression in terms of exponentials and polynomials doesn't exist though.

Comment: Excellent example for question 2 James. This is an implicitly defined sequence which, if you're correct, can't be defined explicitly - according to what I mean by explicit.

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "can be calculated".  For any integer sequence, I can define a function $f(n)$ as that which returns the $n^{th}$ term and another function $g(n)$ which returns the difference of the $n^{th}$ and $(n-1)^{th}$ terms.

Comment: What I mean, in terms of 'calculated as a function of', is that mathematical operations (eg +, ^, sin) are performed on one or more data input, such as the (n-1)th term, to yield an output integer.

Comment: My point is that you need to clearly define what class of functions are allowed.  Without that there is no hope.  For example, one function would be the size of a sequence.  If you have that one, the second class must include the first, as it can get $n$ from the list of previous values, then perform any calculation that the first does.

Comment: What you call "implicitly defined" is usually called "recursively defined". Also, the Fibonacci sequence is defined not only by its recurrence relation $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ ($n\ge 2$) but also by the initial conditions $F_0=0$, $F_1=1$. Different initial conditions yield a different sequence. A well-known example is [Lucas numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number) that satisfy the same recurrence relation, $L_n=L_{n-1}+L_{n-2}$ ($n\ge 2$) but slightly different initial conditions, $L_0=2$, $L_1=1$.

Answer (score 1):

See what you can do with, say, $F(0) = 0,$ followed by 
$$  F(x) = 1 + \left( F(x -1) \right)^2  $$